# Going Back and Forth between View Controllers with Back Button Always Going to Root

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have three View Controllers in a Navigation Controller. One is the root, and the others should appear if conditionA or conditionB is met, respectively.

In case both conditions are true, I want the conditionA View Controller to be shown. If things then change, and conditionA is no longer met, but conditionB still is, I want to show the conditionB View Controller. This means that I want to be able to go from the conditionA View Controller to the conditionB View Controller, and vice versa, until neither condition is met. However, I always want the back button to send users to the root.

To implement this while avoiding errors like ‘Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state’, I’ve taken code from Dave DeLong’s answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11821263/2524427.

```
(void)somethingChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if(!conditionA && !conditionB){return;}

    NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    NSMutableArray *newViewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];
    // preserve the root view controller
    [newViewControllers addObject:[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]];

    if(conditionA)
    {
        // add the new view controller
        [newViewControllers addObject:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"conditionAViewController"]];
        // animatedly change the navigation stack
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers:newViewControllers animated:YES]; 
        return;
    }

    if(conditionB)
    {
        // add the new view controller
        [newViewControllers addObject:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"conditionBViewController"]];
        // animatedly change the navigation stack
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers:newViewControllers animated:YES]; 
    }
}
```

This works almost perfectly. However, if I have the following sequence

1. somethingChanged triggered while only conditionB is met -> conditionB View Controller appears - *as desired*
2. somethingChanged triggered again, but now both conditionA and conditionB are met -> condition A View Controller appears - *as desired*
3. somethingChanged triggered for the third time, now back to initial situation where only conditionB is met -> I return to the root View Controller (with Back button) instead of conditionB View Controller…

How can I keep going back and forth between these View Controllers?

Comment: Have you considered using a custom container view controller instead of the navigation controller?  Since your desired transitions aren't really a match for the push/pop logic of navigation, it might be easier to have a single controller with three children and let it make the decision about which to display.

Comment: I got rid of the navigation controller and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the solution in the question you linked. Try this

1. init your own back button `UIBarButtonItem` as navigationBar's `leftBarButtonItem` in both conditionA View Controller and conditionB view controller
2. wire up with a action

   ```
   - (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {
       [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
   ```

Comment: Your answer and Phillip Mills' comment motivated me to get rid of the navigation controller and manually add navigation bars with a custom back button to my View Controllers. Now it works, thanks!